# how to get user input in textbox while loop in visual c++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

How to get user input in while loop. when the while loop is going on the textbox on my form is not working, It is not taking user input , even i cant click on it to write, while loop is going on. 
After coming out of loop textbox is working normally. So how to take user input while loop is going on?

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

         string arr[10] = { "jsdhfji", "jhsdfjk", "nsdbfgj", "jgjh", "jhjhfj", "hjhf", "hfghd", "hgfghd", "hf", "hh" };
         int i = 0,count=0;

         while (1){
             String^ check = gcnew String(arr[i].c_str());
             label2->Text = check;
             label2->Refresh();
             _sleep(1000);

             if (textBox1->Text == check){
                 count++;
             }

                 i++;
             if (i == 10) break;
         }
         string s123 = to_string(count);
         String^ check1 = gcnew String(s123.c_str());
         String^ text = "Correct Words : "+check1;
         MessageBox::Show(text);
```

}

Comment: You should first understand which programming language you are using. It's *not* C++, even if it has "C++" in its name.

Answer (score 1):

You should use multi threading with textChanged Event handler to get the expected results.